# Save an image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code that's supposed to save a picture (Bitmap) and it doesn't save it and throws an exception every time, what is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace PicConv {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        Bitmap bmp;
        Bitmap bmp2;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++) {
                    Color c = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);
                    byte r = c.R;
                    byte g = c.G;
                    byte b = c.B;

                    byte I = (byte)(0.3 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b);
                    Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(I, I, I);
                    bmp2.SetPixel(x, y, c1);
                }
            }
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp2;
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\pic.bmp");
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            bmp2 = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                if (bmp2 != null) {
                    bmp2.Save(@"c:\test.bmp"); // <- this throws an exception every time and won't save anything
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made it pop up a message box window telling me what the error is and it says "A generic error occured in GDI+".

Comment: Not a good idea to save in the root of your system drive. Try with a temporary folder (C:\TEMP\Test.bmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the way in which you load your image

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\pic.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bmp = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
bmp2 = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();
```

Notice that it is probably unrelated to your problem but it is better to avoid writing in the root of your system drive. Usually this location requires elevated access permissions.

Comment: Also, it was all because of the fact that i was in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it to a folder instead of just C:. Otherwise, I think you need to run with admin privileges.